# Angular directive dont works inside a 'controller as'

Tags: angularjs

I have a single controller

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function() {
  this.message = 'Hello';
  this.method = function() {
    return this.message;
  };
});

module.directive('MyDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
     argument: '=',
     method: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.argument); //undefined!
      scope.method(); // undefined
    }
  };
});
```

the template

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
  <p data-ng-bind="ctrl.message"></p> <!-- Works! -->
  <p data-ng-bind="ctrl.method()"></p> <!-- Works too! -->
  <div data-my-directive data-method="ctrl.method" data-argument="ctrl.message">
</div>
```

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: the angular version is 1.3.9

Comment: Does it work when replacing `ctrl.message` with a value? In other words - are you certain that it's not the directive which is responsible for it?

Comment: When it is replaced by a value, works. Example `data-argument="'hello'"`

Comment: Just works fine to me.http://plnkr.co/edit/7u9OFUFT0EdtUbE6rBlc?p=preview with one change to make function binding to take expression as `data-method="ctrl.method()"`